# iterate over map within map

Tags: c++, dictionary, loops

I have a problem iterating over the second map in a map.

```
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<string, map<string, string> > mymap;
map<string, map<string, string> >::iterator itm;
pair<map<string, map<string, string> >::iterator,bool> retm;

for( itm=mymap.begin(); itm!=mymap.end(); ++itm)
{
cout << "first:\t" << it->first << endl;
}
```

How can I iterate over the second map and get both first and second keys/values?

And the second question is, how can I "insert" into the first and second map using the "insert" function that comes with maps?

I hope someone has a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

map<string, map<string, string> > mymap;
map<string, map<string, string> >::iterator itm;
pair<map<string, map<string, string> >::iterator,bool> retm;

int main() {

  /* populate: */
  mymap.insert(make_pair ("something", map<string, string>()));
  mymap["something"].insert(make_pair ("2", "two"));

  /* traverse: */
  for( itm=mymap.begin(); itm!=mymap.end(); ++itm)
  {
    cout << "first:\t" << itm->first << endl;

    for (map<string, string>::iterator inner_it = (*itm).second.begin();
        inner_it != (*itm).second.end(); 
        inner_it++) {
      cout << (*inner_it).first << " => " << (*inner_it).second << endl;
    }   

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Martin: OK, but that's true of most SO questions. That's usually why they are questions...

Comment: This question is clearly asking two things: how do you generally access the inner map; and how do you insert a new element.  They're not asking about the it/itm typo.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is about the whole answer. I will upvote it. If I could I would upvote perreal, Kerrek SB and Martin's answers.

Comment: Oh, apologies, I had misread there to be a `typedef`, when actually `itm` is an object!

Answer (score 4):

`it->second` will give you the "second map". Just iterate over that.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a second iterator in an additional nested for-loop to iterate over the it->second just like you iterated over mymap.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>::iterator outer_it;
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator                        inner_it;

for (outer_it it1 = mymap.begin(); it1 != mymap.end(); ++it1)
{
    for (inner_it it2 = it1->second.begin(); it2 != it1->second.end(); ++it2)
    {
        std::cout << "first: " << it1->first << ", second: " << it2->first
                  << ", value: " << it2->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

To insert:

```
mymap["hello"]["world"] = "foo";
```

Or, using `insert`:

```
mymap["hello"].insert(std::make_pair("world", "foo"));
```

If you want to insert multiple values, perform the outer lookup only once:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> & m = mymap["hello"];
m.insert(std::make_pair("world", "foo"));
m.insert(std::make_pair("word",  "boo"));
m.insert(std::make_pair("lord",  "coo"));
```

Comment: Yes but I meant using the map::insert function. But I very much like what you did with the first part. Thanks. :)

Comment: @perreal: Thanks, fixed -- I had misread a `typedef` in the OP's code when actually there wasn't any!

Comment: @user1058431: I added some information on avoiding repeated, redundant look-ups.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you can do it like this:

```
for (const auto& outerElem: mymap) {
    cout << "First: " << outerElem.first << endl;
    for (const auto& innerElem: outerElem.second) {
        cout << "  First: " << innerElem.first << endl;
        cout << "  Second: " << innerElem.second << endl;
    }
}
```

In C++03, you can also do this with [BOOST_FOREACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/foreach.html). You cannot use `auto` though, so it's best to typedef each type like this. Using typedefs like this is a good idea anyway.

```
typedef map<string, string> innerMap;
typedef map<string, innerMap> outerMap;
```